# How to Scrape Data from Interactive Web Charts?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was checking this web site for obtaining the year-by-year vehicle sales data.

https://autoalliance.org/energy-environment/advanced-technology-vehicle-sales-dashboard/

It seems like the link eventually point to this site.

https://public.tableau.com/views/AutoAllianceAdvTechVehSalesDashboard/ATVSales?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&:showVizHome=no&:host_url=https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F&:tabs=yes&:toolbar=yes&:animate_transition=yes&:display_static_image=no&:display_spinner=no&:display_overlay=yes&:loadOrderID=0

But I don't know how to proceed now.  There is some very long code (starting from line 107) that I don't understand..

Anyone with suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any code? What do you want to scrape from the website?

Comment: No I don't have any code yet.  I am trying to get the vehicle sales data by vehicle type from 2013 to 2019.